# Can not suspend my thread! Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I can't figure out what is the problem in the following code:
I have a thread that can be suspended and resumed
Code bellow:

```
public class CustomThread implements Runnable {   

    private volatile boolean stop;  
    private volatile boolean suspend;  

    String[] names = new String[]{  
            "A", "B","C","D","E", "F", "G","H","I","J","K", "L"  
    };  

    public CustomThread(){  
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(names));  
        System.out.println("Available names:");  
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(names));  

    }  

    @Override  
    public void run() {  

        while(!stop){             
            synchronized (this) {  
                if(suspend){  
                    try {  
                        System.out.println("Got suspended");  
                        wait();  
                        System.out.println("Resumed");  
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                        System.out.println("Got interupted");  
                    }  
                }     
                else System.out.println("Suspend false");  
            }  
            int randomIdx = new Random().nextInt(names.length);  
            System.out.println(names[randomIdx]);             
        }  
    }  

    public synchronized void suspend(){  
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Suspend true");  
        suspend = true;  
    }  

    public synchronized void resume(){  
        suspend = false;  
        notify();  
    }    
}
```

I run the following simple code:

```
public class CustomTest {  

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {  
        CustomThread c = new CustomThread();  
        Thread t = new Thread(c);  
        t.start();  
        Thread.sleep(5000);  
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");         
        c.suspend();  
    }  
}
```

What I am expecting to see is:
Thread custom runs, main sleeps, main suspends the custom thread by `c.suspend()` and since `main` terminates and noone resumes the thread, the thread remains in `wait` state.
But what I see instead is that the `CustomThread` prints continually `Suspend false` and an element from `names`.

What is the problem here? It is like the `Thread.sleep(5000)` and `c.suspend()` in main don't do anything.

Comment: I have just only a vague idea of what you are saying, but this is consistently what happens in any run

Comment: I think you are saying that the thread woke up due to JVM and suspend was false.But what happened to `suspend = true` from the `c.suspend()` in this case?

Comment: I am not sure I understand - I just ran your code, it keeps printing "Suspend False" and a letter for 5 seconds (your Thread.sleep) then when your main calls `c.suspend()` I see the `Got suspended` message and the whole thing hangs. Is that not what you see?

Comment: Yes, in fact it runs as advertised. OP, your problem is probably that you are running this through Eclipse and you are overwhelming the console. Put a shorter delay in main and you'll se good results.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik out of curiosity: the lock is released while calculating the random number and printing `names[randomIdx]`. Is it possible that the JVM has included those 2 statements within the synchronized block (is it allowed)?

Comment: @assylias I got sidetracked by the code and I was wrong about the deadlock. The deadlock would indeed happen if you change `if(suspended)` to `while(suspended)`. And yes, I think you are right about the JVM being allowed to pull those statements in. I just don't know the detailed rules. But even if it pulled them in, the lock would get released regularly.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:Yes I use eclipse.If I put `Thread.sleep(50)` instead I see the suspend happening! But I don't understand what you mean by deadlock

Comment: If you run the inner loop -- `while(suspended)` -- then you never release the lock (never exit the `synchronized` block). Consequently the main thread cannot acquire the lock to enter the method `suspend`. That method doesn't need `synchronized`, anyway (same for `resume`).

Comment: But `suspend` becomes `false` eventually.So why would I never exit the block?If you add as answer this and the note on eclipse I will accept it

Comment: You are right. The loop would have to say `while (!suspend)` to get problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine as written, but your problem is probably that you are running this through Eclipse and you are overwhelming the console. Put a shorter delay in `main` and you'll see good results.

Note: your `suspend` method doesn't need to be `synchronized` as it only writes to a `volatile` variable.

Comment: Volatile just means that the memory write is visible, right? Does it guarantee that the read-write is atomic as well?

Comment: No, if you need compare-and-swap semantics or similar, you need an `AtomicXxx` class from `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: So if it is not atomic, why do you say that `synchronized` not needed since it is `volatile`?

Comment: That method is only doing the write. That single write **is** atomic.

Comment: Because it is on a primitive variable?

Comment: Every write to a volatile var is atomic and all actions done by the writing thread prior to the write `happen-before` all actions done by a reading thread following the read of that value. That means that even if you write a reference, the referred object's state as of the moment of writing will be safely transported to the reading thread.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if(suspend)` you should have `while(suspend)`, see the explanation in javadoc here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29

From the javadoc of `Object.wait()`:

> ...interrupts and spurious wakeups are
>   possible, and this method should always be used in a loop

Comment: Same issue changing `if` to `while(suspend)`